# How to understand Sprite coordinates in AddSprite function?

Tags: c++, direct2d

I have a bitmap with a sprite on it. Say the sprite with coordinates (0,0)-(5,4) in the bitmap coordinate space (source rectangle). I put it onto the destination rectangle with the same coordinates (0,0)-(5,4) in the render target coordinate space (`ID2D1SpriteBatch::AddSprites` function). But it draws the sprite with the cut right and bottom edged by one pixel.

If I use a source rectangle with (0,0)-(6,5) coordinates (that's plus one pixel), it solves the problem and Direct2D draws the sprite as needed. OK, but I do not understand why I have to use "one pixel plus" technic to draw "the uncut" sprite? What's wrong with sprite coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The [`D2D_RECT_F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcommon/ns-dcommon-d2d_rect_f) structure that you are passing to `ID2D1SpriteBatch::AddSprites` as the `destinationRectangles` is documented as:

> Represents a rectangle defined by the coordinates of the upper-left corner (left, top) and the coordinates of the lower-right corner (right, bottom).

Note that you are specifying the *corners* on the destination device context, not the inclusive starting/ending pixel rows/columns. Therefore, if you draw from `(0,0)` to `(0,0)`, you would be asking to draw a 0-sized rectangle, rather than a 1x1 rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I point out 0,0 coordinates in the source rectangle, the I cover 0,0 pixel and that's OK, but when I point out 5,4 coordinates, then I actually cover only 4,3 pixel. And that well describes my problem !

Comment: @BorisChistyakov You're welcome! For the *destination*, yes. For the source rectangle, note that it is specified in `UINT32` and refers to actual pixels (from what I can see in the docs). In any case, if you are drawing the entire bitmap, you should pass `nullptr` as the docs suggest for performance (and clarity).

Comment: I will test again. Good remark about destination. What if the destination, not source, cuts a sprite ?...

Comment: @BorisChistyakov Not sure I understand... What do you mean by cutting the sprite? I was suggesting to pass `nullptr` for the source (since I guess you want to draw the entire bitmap). If you need to draw a subset, then of course, you will need to pass a particular source rectangle.

Comment: My initial question was about the source rectangle coordinates. I had two versions "who" cuts the image of my sprite - destination or source rectangles. After a few tests I discovered that the destination rectangle cannot cut the image, it scales the image in any case. But the source rectangle, if I define the wrong coordinates, cuts. I did not understand how to define right/bottom coordinates for a sprite rectangle. Now I do.  It is not very obvious from the docs that what right/bottom coordinates of the pixel must be used in the code against what I see from a bitmap picture tool like Paint.